# guild.members.forEach is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on a bot that sends direct message to everyone on the server.
Here's my code that generates errors. Can someone help me?

Here's the error: "TypeError: guild.members.forEach is not a function"

````js
client.on("message", msg => {
 if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith("$private")) {
   let text = msg.content.slice("$private".length); // cuts off the /private part
   let guild = msg.guild
   guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username)); ```
````

Comment: does $private ever iterate through objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Discord.js v12 (the latest version), `guild.members` is now a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager). Use this instead:

```js
guild.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```